# Why are my class properties undefined when i run a function which is tied to an onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to make a noughts and crosses game with each cell being an object of the Cell class, each class will contain multiple properties such as the div element that specific cell is tied to in HTML so that i can then change the style of that div if it is clicked.

However when trying to assign each Cells onclick attribute to a method in the class the class variables i had defined in the constructor were undefined. I could not work out of it was the scope, i have attempted using  `var self = this;`  in the constructor and using that instead of this for the methods. I have read other multiple questions similar to this however i cannot seem to fix the problem.

```
   class Cell 
    {    

        constructor(cellDiv) 
        {
            this.clicked = false;
            this.cellDiv = cellDiv;
            this.player = 7;
            this.cellDiv.className = "cell";      
        }
        output()
        { 
            console.log(this.player);
            console.log(this.clicked);
            console.log(this.cellDiv);
        }        
    }

    var grid = [];

    function buildBoard ()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i ++)
        {
            grid.push(new Cell(document.createElement("div")));

            document.getElementById("gameBoard")
            .appendChild(grid[i].cellDiv);


            grid[i].cellDiv.onclick = grid[i].output;

            grid[i].output();

        }


    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
         <head>
            <meta charset = "UTF-8">
            <title>Task 3</title>
            <link rel = "stylesheet"; type = "text/css"; href = "stylesheet.css" />
        </head>


    <body>
    <script type = "application/javascript"; src ="main.js"></script>
    <script type = "application/javascript"; src ="cell.js"></script>


        <div class = "gameBoard"; id = "gameBoard"></div>







    <script type="text/javascript">
        buildBoard();
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

At the moment this creates 9 cells, places them all on a board, assigns their onclick attribute and then outputs what i would expect to be outputted when i click the cell. However, when the output function is called in the for loop everything is outputted as expected but when i click each div i receive undefined variables.

```
<code>
main.js:38 7
main.js:39 false
main.js:38 undefined
main.js:39 undefined
</code>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the `output` method to your class. There are various approaches, but the most compact way to do that is to assign it to an arrow function.

```
class Cell {
  constructor () { ... }

  output = () =>                                                                                    
  {                                                                                                 
    console.log(this.player);                                                                     
    console.log(this.clicked);                                                                    
    console.log(this.cellDiv);                                                                    
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Would you mind please marking my answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark on the side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `this` in function is determined when it's called, not at the time of creation.

So when `output` function is called, `this` does not refer to the cell object anymore.

Solution: use arrow function which use `this` of surrounding scope at the time of creation